# Как ускорить нахождение строки с помощью regex?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, lxml

У меня есть первый файл(размером около 1-3 кб) несколько строк в котором выглядят так:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

И есть второй файл(размером 1.2 Гб) в котором строка выглядит так:

```
<root><img>url</img><title>Name1</title>(здесь еще несколько тегов)</root>
```

Второй файл содержит все имена первого файла(и также имена таких же файлов как 1), только с доп. информацией.

Мне необходимо что бы код проходился по каждой строке файла 1, брал оттуда имя и по нему искал тег с тем же именем в файле 2. После того, как тот найдет тег, содержащий нужное имя нужно скопировать родительский тег root и все что в нем находится.

Вот код который я написал:

```
import re

my_list = [12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24] #идентификатор файла после имени
with open('main_data_file.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    txt = ''.join(f.readlines())
    for i in my_list:
        cat_name = "catalog_" + str(i) + ".xml"
        data_name = "main_data_catalog" + str(i) + ".xml"
        with open(cat_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as g, open(data_name, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as x:
            for element in g.readlines():
                line_regexp = r'.*<title>{}</title>.*'.format(element.strip())
                matches = re.search(line_regexp, txt, re.MULTILINE)
                try:
                    x.write(matches.group(0) + "\n")
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
```

Он рабочий, только он ооочень медленно работает и мне нужно ускорить этот код

Вопрос: Как можно ускорить данных код, хотя бы до строчки в 2-3 секунды(вместо строчки в 10-15 секунд)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Искал и нашел достаточно производительный метод через `set()`

```
data_set = set()
with open('main_data_file.xml', 'r') as f:
    data_set.update(f.readlines())
    data_name = "main_data_catalog" + str(i) + ".xml"
    with open("names.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as g, open(catalog.xml, 'a') as x:
        for line in g.readlines():
            line_regexp = '<title>%s</title>' % line.strip()
            # print('Searching line:' + line_regexp)
            for element in data_set:
                if line_regexp in element:
                    x.write(element)
                    # print('Element found ' + line.strip() + "\n")
```

Работает на достаточно высоких скоростях и меня устраивает, если есть советы по оптимизации, то пишите в комментарии